# Umbraco Database Question- Adding custom tables

Tags: database, umbraco

I'm working on a site managed by Umbraco.  I need to store data about images and clients.    I don't think there is any way I can store that data in the existing tables.

Is there any reason I shouldn't add the tables I'll need to the Umbraco database, rather than creating a separate DB?  I like Umbraco so far but the documentation is a little thin and I haven't found any suggestions one way or the other.

TIA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have built a site using Umbraco, with a separate application with a database of vehicles. I used the same database as Umbraco is using, and prefixed all my custom app tables with a few letters to distinguish them easily (eg: vehicles_xxx)

I have had no problems with this arrangement, and don't believe there's much risk involved. Of course you'll need to take care when upgrading Umbraco (never upgrade in the live environment before fully testing, and preferably do it locally anyway), however its unlikely an upgrade script will ever alter or delete any tables that it does not know about.

There's heaps of doco available for umbraco now - much more than when i started.. however a question like this is always best for the forums. :)

all the best
greg

Answer (score 4):

You might use the Umbraco API to store and retrieve your data and enjoy the ease of not having to worry bout tables and much more. Or you create your own tables. Do as Gregorius says - using umbraco db is fine.

Your choice depends on:

- do you have a lot of data?
- do you have a large relation model?

If not - then go with Umbraco API

The rest of the answers you'll find on http://our.umbraco.org

/Jesper Ordrup

Comment: Which part of the API are you referring to? Is there documentation on how to store data in the Umbraco database using the Umbraco API?